# Right Super key not opening Dash on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, 18.04, activities-overview

I have an odd issue with <kbd>Super</kbd> key. As for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, it isn't opening the dash menu any more.

My mechanical keyboard layout is Brazilian. The only difference is that it has a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key where the left <kbd>Super</kbd> is supposed to be. So I only have the right <kbd>Super</kbd>.

I tried to keybind, but there is no option for the dash menu. I know some folks had this issue with Unity and they fixed with a tweak application. But now we have GNOME.

Comment: Same problem on my Kinesis Advantage2 keyboard, there is no left Super :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use *(GNOME) Tweaks* to achieve your goal.

First install Tweaks by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

(or `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`).

Then launch Tweaks and go to "*Keyboard & Mouse*" section. Select "**Right Super**" for the "*Overview Shortcut*" option.

[image]

Comment: I saw that. It opens the Window Overview instead of the Apps menu. At least it has a search. 
edit: looks like its default on 18.04. An intended change.

Comment: @Sam That is the expected behaviour. For apps list hit Super+A.

Comment: That's something already  but how to have both super keys work and not just having one of them disabled?

Comment: @wranvaud Consider asking a new question.

Comment: I feel this UI design is a bit confusing: it would be more intuitive if both Super keys did the same just like Shift and Control. Also there is no indication of it in the default dash. Sad :-(

Comment: I already bought an Akko 68 layout keyboard. It has one super key but the key didn't work with ubuntu 18 and 20. Tweaks tool is a great tool to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

edit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
and search for `<RWIN>` and set it to `Super_L` instead of `Super_R`

`key <RWIN> {        [ Super_L               ]       };`

you could try it temporarily by running the following:

```bash
 xkbcomp $DISPLAY output.xkb
 # edit output.xkb and adjust the <RWIN> binding
 xkbcomp output.xkb $DISPLAY
```