# Remap a key permanently

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04, gnome-shell

I know this question has been ask and answer often but none of the solution found seems to work properly.
I'd like to have both my super keys to work at the same time. I need to map <kbd>R-Win</kbd> (key code 134) to  <kbd>L-Win</kbd> (keycode 133).
On Ubuntu 20.04 I've tried the following:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L"
```

it works but the change is not even permanent during my session, I have to type it regularly 
 in order for the command to be effective.
I've tried to put the command in my user's `crontab`, in startup script for my session.
I've put :

```
keycode 134 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
```

in `~/.Xmodmap`, `~/.xmodmaprc` and `~/.xmodmap` none of them seems to be used or load at session login.

I've also tried to edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` to add the following modifier:

`modifier_map Mod4   { Super_L, Super_R };`

However no effect.

Conclusion, so far the only solution that *works* is when using `xmodmap` interactively, but the effect is temporary and needs to be input several in a day of work.

I'm on an almost brand new minimal installation of Ubuntu 20.04. any help would be very much appreciate so I can finally use both my Super key in GnomeShell.

PS: I've also tried `setxkbmap -option rwin:lwin`but it has no effect neither when put in `/etc/default/keyboard`  `XKBOPTIONS` option nor when execute interactively.

Comment: no just to have both keys work at the same time in gnome shell

Comment: I don't want to use shortcut of gnome shell those are working, i want to access the dash menu with any super key. I have a laptop that doesn't have a right super key. but my external keyboard does and i love using the right key instead of the left key, but if i choose the right super key in GnomeShell then i can't open dash menu without an external keyboard.

Comment: and my install of ubuntu is brand new I've disable all my modification and dash menu won't open when using right super. see this, this is the same issue but i want both super key to work not just one. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029001/right-super-key-not-opening-dash-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: All shortcut works with both super key no doubt, but the Super key to dash menu (a bit like Windows with the start menu) wasn't possible on both key. Anyway it look like you propose the perfect solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround to Achieve the Overview Action with Right Super..

install the package `xcape`

```
sudo apt install xcape
```

Create a startup application preferences with below command.

```
xcape -e 'Super_R=Super_L'
```

[image]

Comment: looks amazing, even working after suspend and lockscreen... I think it might be it. I'm going to check in the afternoon if it's still working properly and accept if it does :-)
Thank you very much.

Comment: I can confirm this is amazing and it works flawlessly despite any change of setup. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu 22.04 there's `input-remapper` which works on X11 and Wayland. It can remap any key to any other key.